# Monitor multiple variable amounts of processes' start and exit

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, monitor

I need some code to monitor when a program starts and stops, asynchronously.

I can work with VB.NET or C# Code. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#.NET Monitoring for a Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874744/c-net-monitoring-for-a-process)

Answer (score 2):

This is the method that would do the actual monitoring. As far as a dynamic config file, your master thread that is spawning these monitor threads could use `FileSystemWatcher`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx to monitor an xml/text file with the process names. You could pass in a cancellation token into the function and on each iteration check if the token was cancelled.

```
static Task MonitorProcessAsync(string process, Action<string> startAction, Action<string> exitAction)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        bool isProcessRunning = false;

        while (true)
        {
            int count = Process.GetProcessesByName(process).Count();
            if (count > 0 && !isProcessRunning)
            {
                startAction(process);
                isProcessRunning = true;
            }
            else if (count == 0 && isProcessRunng)
            {
                exitAction(process);
                isProcessRunning = false;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Example

```
Action<string> startAction = (process) => Console.WriteLine(process + " Started!");
Action<string> exitAction = (process) => Console.WriteLine(process + " Stopped!");
MonitorProcessAsync("notepad.exe", startAction, exitAction);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to rephrase my question, I have to monitor both start and exit of processes.

Comment: That's alright. I modified it to monitor both the start and stop of the process. It uses a boolean to represent the previous state of the process and checks that against the current count to see if it's state has chanced, if it has it executes the appropriate start or exist action.