# C#.NET Monitoring for a Process

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

We have this 3rd party in house app that's a little buggy and for now, till it's fixed, in our Citrix environment, I need to keep an eye on it and kill the process if it runs too long. I was able to poll for it and kill it if it was running but that's quite dirty and would require me to use a scheduled task.  I want a service to monitor and detect it then kill it if it's running too long.

So I started a Windows Service project in Visual Studio and I found [this code from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) which registers with WMI using ManagementEventWatcher:

```
        string pol = "2";
        string appName = "MyApplicationName";

        string queryString =
            "SELECT *" +
            "  FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
            "WITHIN  " + pol +
            " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
            "   AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + appName + "'";

        // You could replace the dot by a machine name to watch to that machine
        string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

        // create the watcher and start to listen
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.OnEventArrived);
        watcher.Start();
```

The problem with this code is that where it says "this.OnEventArrived", I get the following error:

Error   1   'MyServiceApp.Service1' does not contain a definition for 'OnEventArrived' and no extension method 'OnEventArrived' accepting a first argument of type 'MyServiceApp.Service1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What's the deal?

Comment: Well, *have* you defined your event handler / callback method that you are subscribing to the event `EventArrived`, `this.OnEventArrived`? What signature does it have?

Comment: Wow, I have no idea. Obviously no, but I'm not sure what to do in order to do that. I assume I need to write a method called "OnEventArrived" that it runs when the event arrives? I'm not even sure what parameters it needs. That CodeProject article doesn't even bother mentioning this.

Comment: You got a good answer below now, but I suggest that you take a moment to study C# delegates and events. This kind of thing will come up fairly often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for this can be found on MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.eventarrived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

OnEventArrived should look like this.

```
private void OnEventArrived(object sender, ManagementEventArgs args)
{
//do your work here
}
```

Here is a sample program that will monitor notepad. You probably want to read more on WMI to see if there is a better way. You can launch notepad via the start menu and you will see Notepad started out put to the console.  On exiting it will print Notepad Exited.  I do not know all the messages that can be output.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string pol = "2";
        string appName = "Notepad.exe";

        string queryString =
            "SELECT *" +
            "  FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " +
            "WITHIN  " + pol +
            " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
            "   AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + appName + "'";

        // You could replace the dot by a machine name to watch to that machine
        string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

        // create the watcher and start to listen
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, queryString);
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived);
        watcher.Start();
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void OnEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceCreationEvent"))
            Console.WriteLine("Notepad started");
        else if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceDeletionEvent"))
            Console.WriteLine("Notepad Exited");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName);
    }
```

Comment: I figured that out just now as well, but the question is, what work goes in there? He has some confusing code on that codeproject page about notepad but it doesn't work because there's no "ProcessInfo" class that I can find. Like if I set the app to notepad.exe then if I start notepad I wanna go MessageBox.Show("Notepad Opened"); just to test.